# Неравномерная вероятность, класс Random

Tags: java, android, случайные-числа

Как можно увеличить вероятность появления того или иного числа при реализации объекта класса `Random`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В зависимости от того, насколько серьёзна ваша задача, есть два подхода к её решению.

**Правильный подход для серьёзных задач**

Если вы хотите, чтобы случайные числа у вас были распределены не равномерно,
а по какому-нибудь закону распределения (например, нормальное распределение),
то вы используете *метод обратного преобразования* (англ. Inverse transform sampling).

Суть его, если вкратце, заключается в том, что к случайным числам с равномерным распределением (uniform distribution) вы применяете обратную функцию того распределения которое вас интересует.

[image: Преобразование равномерного распределения к нормальному]
*Преобразование равномерного распределения к нормальному; источник: http://habrahabr.ru/post/208684/*

Например, в этой Python-строке (я приведу пример на Python, но на Java или другом языке программирования по сути всё будет точно так же) мы получаем список из 1000 случайных чисел распределённых по определённому закону (обратная функция от этого распределения описывается `inverted_function`)

```
[inverted_function(random.random()) for x in range(1000)]
```

Подробнее вы можете найти в моём ответе на аналогичный вопрос в английском StackOverflow:

- [Fast arbitrary distribution random sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100716/fast-arbitrary-distribution-random-sampling/21100998) (англ.)

Кроме того, посмотрите побольше о методе обратного преобразования:

- [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_обратного_преобразования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) (рус.)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling (англ.)
- [Преобразование равномерно распределенной случайной величины в нормально распределенную](http://habrahabr.ru/post/208684/) (рус.) (хабр.) — неплохая статья, где этот метод объяснён на пальцах

Тот факт, что вам это нужно в Android'е, естественно, ничего не меняет. Математические основы данного метода остаются теми же.

**Примитивный метод для простейших случаев**

Если вам не нужен правильный мегаподход, описанный мною выше, а вы просто хотите, чтобы одно число выпадало в два раза чаще другого, то делается всё элементарно.

Вы делаете массив с границами интервалов, в который попадёт число.
Размеры интервалов делаете в соответствии с соотношеними требуемых вероятностей.
Далее генерируете число в диапазоне от 0 до 1 и смотрите в какой интервал оно попало.

Другой способ (такой же уровень примитивности): повторять нужные вам вещи соответствующее число раз в соответствии с требуемой вероятностью, выбирать вещь случайно (опять приведу пример на Python с вашего позволения):

```
pos = ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 4 + ['C'] * 3
print random.choice(pos)
```

В этом примере вероятность выпадения `A` — 30%, `B` — 40% и `C` — 30%.