# C# Random: задать вероятность

Tags: c#, случайные-числа

Я знаю, что для генерации случайного числа в C# используется "Random", но не знаю как это использовать и что менять в классе и библиотеках, а также хотел бы узнать как задать определённую вероятность выпадения числа

Comment: Похожий вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420408

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1203937/220553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, что мы хотим сделать такую систему, в которой событие А наступает с вероятностью 0.6, а событие B с вероятностью 0.4.

Тогда одно из решений задачи такое:

```java
var rand = new Random();
    
if (rand.NextDouble() < 0.6) {
    eventA();
} else {
    eventB();
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, а можно ли как-то задать значение rand, а также нужно ли использовать какую-либо библиотек и менять название класса?

Comment: @Nikichka_Dev поясните, не понял вашего вопроса. Вы хотите хранить значение вероятности в переменной? Дополнительные классы помимо Random не понадобятся.

Comment: Сам немного не понял что написал) Можно ли задать вероятность, максимальное значение которой 100? То есть чтобы вероятность можно было задать например 88 из 100

Comment: @Nikichka_Dev ну если вам принципиально именно в целых числах от 0 до 100, то просто вместо условия в моём примере напишите random.Next(0, 100) < 88